# javascript regex not matching last group; extract time from string

Tags: javascript, regex

In the match

```
'meeting room 3 @ 5 am - 6 pm bob'
.match(/(@|at)?\s*?(\d+)\s*?(am|pm|AM|PM)?\s*?-\s*?(\d+)\s*?(am|pm|AM|PM)?/)
```

Why does the last `pm` not match?

The result is `"["@ 5 am - 6","@","5","am","6",null]"`

I expect that `null` to be `pm`

Thanks

Comment: Remove `?` from all [`\s*?`](https://regex101.com/r/jZI3RS/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all the `\s*?` greedy (especially the last one which is the culprit):

```
/(@|at)?\s*(\d+)\s*(am|pm|AM|PM)?\s*-\s*(\d+)\s*(am|pm|AM|PM)?/
                                               ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WSD8Hm/2/)

The point is that `(\d+)\s*?(am|pm|AM|PM)?` matches and captures 1 or more digits with `(\d+)`, then the regex engine tries to match `(am|pm|AM|PM)?` pattern, not `\s*?`, because `\s*?` is a lazily quantified atom, and is thus skipped at first. The `(am|pm|AM|PM)?` pattern can match an empty string, and it does. It matches the empty string right after the digits, and the regex engine calls it a day returning a valid match.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize the regex engine skips lazy matches at first. Makes sense, though.